# Equivalent LinQ Query

Tags: linq-to-sql

Can someone help convert this query to SQL. I need this in linQ and I dont have write perms to get alternative for Storedprocedure. So linQ is the only way for me now to get it used with Silverlight

```
SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(BGID),0)AS BGCOUNT,CASE SOURCE.PRIORITY
WHEN 1 THEN  'P1'
WHEN 2 THEN  'P2'
WHEN 3 THEN  'P3'
END AS PRIORITY FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT PRIORITY  AS PRIORITY FROM BGS WHERE PRIORITY IS NOT NULL)AS SOURCE
 LEFT OUTER JOIN BGS ON BGS.PRIORITY = SOURCE.PRIORITY AND        
       TREEPATH NOT LIKE '%Prod%' AND TREEPATH LIKE '%TMS%' AND
       TREEPATH NOT LIKE 'BG\structure\Aut\TMS%' AND STATUS = 'ACTIVE'  AND
       (ASSIGNEDTO = 'cato14' OR ASSIGNEDTO IN 
       ('useratadi','userajsudh','useramanna','useritnaga'))
GROUP BY SOURCE.PRIORITY
ORDER BY SOURCE.PRIORITY
```

Comment: Asking for help implies you have already done something and run into specific problems. At the moment it just looks like you're asking us to do your work for you. Why don't you show us what you've done so far, and ask specific questions about the parts you're stuck on? Here's a handy tool for experimenting with Linq queries: http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Shouldn't do so much formatting in the database.  You do backflips just to get empty group out.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have SQL you're happy with, you can skip translating it to linq by calling `DataContext.ExecuteQuery<T>`.

Comment: But can i use it in silverlight?

Comment: If you could use DataContext in silverlight, you can use this method.  If you couldn't use DataContext, you couldn't have written a linqtosql query anyway.

Comment: so u mean to say that we can execute sql queries in Silverlight using this.. Am I correct? I was of the impression that we cant directly use sql queries to connect to DB and it has to be via wcf/linQ

Comment: No.  I mean to say that a linqtosql query wouldn't have helped you anyway, since you can't use DataContext directly from the client in silverlight without full trust.